# Mysql Syntax Error on import

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a mysqldump and when I get to the following line I get an error.

/*!50001 VIEW `v_categories` AS select `C`.`categoryID` AS `categoryID`,`C`.`mainCategoryID` AS `mainCategoryID`,`C`.`categoryName` AS `categoryName`,`M`.`name` AS 
 `name`,`C`.`visible` AS `visible`,`M`.`priority` AS `main_priority`,`C`.`Priority` AS `priority` from (`categories` `C` join `categories_main` `M`) where (`M`.`id` = `C`.`mainCategoryID`) */;

The error is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VIEW `v_categories` AS select `C`.`categoryID` AS `categoryID`,`C`.`mainCategory' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste what's before `VIEW v_categories`?

Comment: There should be a `create` before the `view` in order to create a view.

Comment: Heres the query from the dump file

/*!50001 DROP TABLE `v_categories`*/;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_categories`*/;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`lunchesr_u5ser`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `v_categories` AS select `C`.`categoryID` AS `categoryID`,`C`.`mainCategoryID` AS `mainCategoryID`,`C`.`categoryName` AS `categoryName`,`M`.`name` AS 

`name`,`C`.`visible` AS `visible`,`M`.`priority` AS `main_priority`,`C`.`Priority` AS `priority` from (`categories` `C` join `categories_main` `M`) where (`M`.`id` = 

`C`.`mainCategoryID`) */;